# Can't get Discord.js example code to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Try as I might, I can't figure out why this basic example code won't work. I am a complete newbie to Java Script. I can't figure out why the line `GatewayIntentBits.Guilds` tosses the error. When I comment that line out, it starts fine. Here is what I am trying to run and the error message. I'm sorry for this ultra-basic question; I feel dumb. Can someone please explain it to me? I've been over the documentation and haven't found the answer.

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds
] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,] });
                                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Guilds' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joshua\projectSpace\CivBot\index.js:6:57)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: What version of DJS are you utilizing?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It is the newest version. I installed it by running `npm install discord.js` after installing Node.js version 16.17.0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what happened, but I decided to uninstall and then reinstall Discord.js using npm, and it's working now. Thank you for trying to help me out. It all looked correct.

Uninstall/reinstall is right behind, turning it off and back on again. ‍♂️

Comment: You were most likely using a DJS version prior to v14 where `GatewayIntentBits` did not exist.